# app.yml error whe i was making pages admin only

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to make pages that require admin login but got this error:

```
    google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unknown url handler type.
    <URLMap 
        auth_fail_action=redirect 
        static_dir=None 
        secure=default 
        http_headers=None 
        url=/admin/.* 
        static_files=None 
        expiration=None 
        upload=None 
        api_endpoint=None 
        script=None 
        application_readable=None 
        position=None 
        login=admin 
        mime_type=None 
        require_matching_file=None
        >
```

the app.yml looks like this but it has the correct application id instead od my_application_id

```
application: my_app_id
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /admin/.*
  login: admin

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `script` is defined for the url `/admin/.*`.

Add `script: ...` for that url.

BTW, `script: main.py` seems wrong. It is not filename of the script, but name of the `Application` object.